# Form submit in jquery dialog box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In the following code, both buttons of dialog box is meant to submit form. But its not submitting when buttons from dialog are clicked. If user chose yes we need to send a value to the posting page. please help me with this.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="edit_billto" id="edit_billto">
  <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_phpshop" />
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $next_page; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next_page" value="<?php echo $next_page; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="<?php echo $Itemid; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="autoship_flag" id="autoship_flag" value="0">
        <input type="submit" id="bill_sumbit" class="button" name="submit" value="<? echo _E_SAVE ?>"  <? echo $submit; ?> />
</form>
```

Jquery part

```
<div id ="alert" style="display:none"> <p> This address is used in autoship. 
    You need to change the address in autoship too? 
    </p></div>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() { 
              $("#alert").dialog({autoOpen: false,
                  modal: true,  
                  buttons: {
                    No : function(){
                    isconfirm = true; 
                    //$("form[name='edit billto']").unbind('submit');
                    $("#edit_billto").submit();
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                    //$("form[name='edit billto']").unbind('submit').submit();
                    }, 
                          Yes: save_info
                    },
                  resizable: true,
                  height: "auto",
                  width: "auto",
                  closeOnEscape: false,
                  title: "Autoship Update"

                    });

            });
            var isconfirm = false; 
            $( "form[name='edit_billto']" ).submit(function(e) {
            //alert(isconfirm);
            if(isconfirm === true){
            return true;
            }

               if(isconfirm === false){

                  e.preventDefault();


                    $( "#alert" ).dialog( "open" );
              }             
            });

     function save_info(){   
              isconfirm = true;       
              $("#autoship_flag").val("1");
              $("form[name='edit_billto']").unbind('submit');
              $("form[name='edit_billto']").submit();          
            }       

            </script>
```

Comment: pls add your html part as as well, cause it can be a wrong selector ;)

Comment: @MarcelD  i have added the html part. please have a look

Comment: I just got the solution. The issue was with button name "submit". Changing that helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, you're `.submit()` isn't working but you could try `.trigger('click')`

Something like this should work:

```
No : function(){
    $("form[name='edit_billto']").off('submit');
    $("#bill_sumbit").trigger('click');
}
```

,